# Mapping key combination with xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to achieve the following mapping
`keycode 135 = <Ctrl-C>`

Is it possible to achieve this in some way?

Comment: Maybe see [my answer on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131900/how-do-i-switch-the-command-key-and-control-key-on-a-macbook-pro-12-04). Might also help, though @Gilles answer looks great.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's not possible with xmodmap. I don't think it's possible with XKB either, but I'm not sure.

Is your aim to have a key that's always identical to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (e.g. in a terminal, it would interrupt the running program), or to have a clipboard copy key? If the latter, try

```
keycode 135 = XF86Copy
```

The `XF86Copy` keysym is intended for a copy-to-clipboard key, but I don't know how many applications have that shortcut out-of-the-box.

If you're on Ubuntu, and possibly even if you aren't, the recommended method to set up additional (“multimedia”) keys is [keytouch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyTouch).

If you really want the key to be equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, your desktop environment or window manager may let you bind the keysym to a command that generates key press and release events for that key combination. If you prefer or must use a DE/WM-agnostic method, you can use [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html) to bind an arbitrary shell command to a key, and [xmacro](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/) to manufacture key events to send to a window. You'll still need to have a keysym associated with the key; a good choice is `F13` (or wherever the numbered function keys on your keyboard leave off). Then put this in your `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"{ echo KeySymPress Control_L; echo KeySym C; echo KeySymRelease Control_L; } | xmacroplay"
  F13
```

You'll need to start `xbindkeys` with your X session — from your `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession` if you have one, or from the appropriate configuration interface in your DE/WM.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to achieve that always when I press the key between right alt and right ctrl (keycode 135) it will be the same as Ctrl+C (This is only example, I'd like to use more keys that aren't utilized on my keyboard and assign them shortcuts Ctrl+A, Ctrl+B, Ctrl+C etc., it doesn't matter what is the function (e.g. copy)). Could you achieve it with another program (xbindkeys, xmacro)?

Comment: You can also try xdotool, it's a bit easier to use than xmacro.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Autokey](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764318) ? It is a much easier way than xbindkeys or xmacro.

Answer (score -2):

xmodmap -e 'keycode 133 = Menu

133 in this case is Super (ubuntu logo on touchpad)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Could you please add some context? Is this a command? A configuration setting? On what operating system? Why would there be an Ubuntu logo on a touchpad? Did you mean keyboard, and even so why would there be an Ubuntu logo there? Could this maybe be specific to _your_ system? In any case, how would this help if the OP wants to map the key to Ctrl+C?

Comment: There also seems to be a missing single quote in your command. The user in the question wants to map `Ctrl+C` with key code 135.