# Is it possible to bind a shell script to a key press

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, bind, bluetooth, xmodmap

I used xev to find the key code for fn-f5 and came up with a little script to toggle the bluetooth on or off.   My question is whether it's possible to bind fn-f5 (keycode 246) to my shell script (bttoggle) using, preferably, xmodmap.

Answer (score 1):

Not with `xmodmap`, which only changes keyboard mappings (what symbols should be produced by what keys). Binding a command to a key combination is task for the window manager (since that is usually the application that receives all X events) - hence it depends on what environment are you using. See Gilles answer at [Mapping key combination with xmodmap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/mapping-key-combination-with-xmodmap).

Comment: Thanks then.  But then this is entirely possible to do with xbindkeys, no?

Comment: Should be, but I haven't tried that. :)