# Debian/Xfce: Keyboard shortcut for home and end keys

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I'm running xfce4 on debian. I'd like to assign keyboard shortcuts for the home and end keys (specifically, to move the cursor to the beginning and end of a line).

In the settings manager there is a gui interface for assigning keyboard shortcuts to commands. However, how could I set a keyboard shortcut (e.g. ctrl+a or ctrl+e) for another key (home or end)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried several tools, like `xmodmap`, `xbindkeys` and `xdotool` to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> to <kbd>End</kbd>.

Problem is: as result, it sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd>-<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>-<kbd>End</kbd> because **keystrike isn't released** and nothing works...

I had to create a script with a sleep :

```
$ cat HomeEnd.sh 
#!/bin/bash
sleep .2
KEY=${1?key}
xdotool key ${KEY}
```

Then I assigned a shorcut with Settings Manager > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts or with command line :

```
$  xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/commands/custom/<Ctrl>Left" -s "${HOME}/bin/HomeEnd.sh Home" -n -t string
$  xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/commands/custom/<Ctrl>Right" -s "${HOME}/bin/HomeEnd.sh End" -n -t string
```

Now It works, I just have to strike <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> and release the keys.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an answer, but the intention was to provide useful hints.

If I read correctly, you are trying to bind a single key to *several keys* presses. The given example is to remap <kbd>End</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (this may be easier to understand).

### `xmodmap` and `xbindkeys`

The classic approach is to check your keycode using `xev` and use X tool like `xmodmap` to remap the keys, as explained in [this answer on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/296437/37165). But this doesn't allow you to remap several keys, mentioned in the answer [for this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/mapping-key-combination-with-xmodmap).

The other approach is to use `xbindkeys` to grab the keys and `xvkbd` to send keys, whose answer was given to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85850/how-to-remap-a-key-combination-to-a-single-key). However, this approach also has its own caveat which cause focus to lose, as mentioned by someone in the comment.

Actually, there is [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/121673/how-do-i-remap-ctrl-j-to-ctrl-c-on-ubuntu) being asked, to remap several key presses to another several key presses (which is one level harder than your request). Unfortunately, the answer has clearly mentioned that you can't achieve that with `xmodmap` and suggesting to use `xbindkeys` instead.

### Alternative: `xdotool`

Some time ago, I was still using a two-button mouse (I know, quite old piece of hardware) and trying to emulate the mouse middle-click. Then, I discovered `xdotool` which was able to emulate mouse clicks, as well as keyboard key presses.

My suggestion is, use `xdotool` to emulate keyboard key press for <kbd>End</kbd> (this will give you a string of command). Then use this command to assign a custom shorcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in Xfce4, which is found under **Settings Manager > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts**.

To build the command using `xdotool`, you can refer to [several examples](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) of which one of them is quoted as follows.

> Example: focus the firefox url bar
>
> ```
> WID=`xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1`
> xdotool windowactivate --sync $WID
> xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+l
>
> # As of version 2.20100623, you can do this simpler version of above:
> xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox" windowactivate --sync key --clearmodifiers ctrl+l
> ```

I haven't used this tool for some time, so I can't give exact answer to your question. In my opinion, using `xdotool` with Xfce4 **Application Shortcuts** is the best solution you can try on Debian Xfce.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that now is using AutoKey:

https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki

To invoke a sequence of keypresses, you create a new script:

```
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+a")
```

and assign it to a hotkey.