# linux keyboard: how remap euro key from sequence ALT 0128 to PgUp?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have laptop Acer Aspire E1-772G and it have Euro key near cursor keys. I do not use Euro and moreover it is implemented so pressing it generate sequence ALT 0 1 2 8

```
# showkey -k
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
^[0^[1^[2^[8keycode  56 press
keycode  82 press
keycode  82 release
keycode  79 press
keycode  79 release
keycode  80 press
keycode  80 release
keycode  72 press
keycode  72 release
keycode  56 release
```

This does a lot of problems, as I press it often by mistake. In `mc` it terminates it, it searches in history and so on

I would like to remap it to PgUp, to behave as expected from block of cursor keys, but i cannot find, where it is defined, or how to remap it. Can somebody help me?

I am using Gentoo with fluxbox and uxrvt as terminal.

PS: `showkey` shows the same even without `X`, but pressing the key just makes a box character (i suppose bad printed euro)

PSS: why it is not duplicate:

- I have the problem without `xbindkeys` running
- I have the problem even without X running
- my problem is opposite - how to stop a key from sending sequencies of codes, not how to send such sequencies - and the solution (run program to send sequence) does not help to "eat" the sequence, nor I can STOP using mentioned program, as it is not running already and the `xmacroplay` is not even present on my laptop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping key combination with xmodmap](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/mapping-key-combination-with-xmodmap)

Comment: I do not think so, as 1) i do not run xbindkey or anything other which makes macro from single key (and have that problem even without X just in shell) and 2) my problem is reverse - how to make a key from macro - showkey tells me a lot of keys was pressed/relesed, while i touched only one key on my keyboard

Comment: It is *not* a duplicate of that question. You can remap sequences of character inputs to strings using XCompose. I'm not sure whether you can specify that Alt is down, though, I don't see an obvious way. It may be worth investigating anyway.

Comment: Given that ALT0128 is a Microsoft thing (to input characters on Windows using decimal code points in Microsoft character sets), I suspect it's done in hardware/firmware, not the (Linux-based) OS.

Answer (score 0):

Given that ALT0128 is a Microsoft thing (to input characters on Windows using decimal code points in Microsoft character sets), I suspect it's done in hardware/firmware, not the (Linux-based) OS.

Probably all Linux sees is exactly the same thing it would see if you had pressed: keydown alt key 0 key 1 key 2 key 8 keyup alt.

To confirm that, you could run:

```
watch -d -n 0.2 cat /proc/interrupts
```

And compare what happens when you type <kbd>A</kbd> with <kbd>€</kbd>.

You should see some number increasing by two for <kbd>A</kbd>, and if it increases by 10 for <kbd>€</kbd>, then there's probably not much you can do at the OS level.

You could check with Acer if there's a way to reprogram the keyboard, or you could physically disconnect, break or glue or tape that key.

While I don't think there's much you can do at the OS or even X11 level, with GNU `screen`, you could bind the sequence of characters that the terminal  would send upon that series of events to some action, like inserting the sequence of characters normally generated upon <kbd>PageUP</kbd> (in ~/.screenrc):

```
bindkey \0330\0331\0332\0338 stuff "\033[2~"
```

Then that would at least for terminal applications that you run within `screen`.