# System wide mapping of a key combination to a single key

Tags: fedora, xkb

I've recently switched from macOS to Fedora, on macOS I used a tool called Karabiner Elements to map the key combinations

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd> to <kbd>[</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ä</kbd> to <kbd>]</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ö</kbd> to <kbd>{</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ä</kbd> to <kbd>}</kbd>

I'm aware of a similar question here:

- [Mapping key combination with xmodmap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/mapping-key-combination-with-xmodmap)

and I've tried to adjust that solution to my case. So far I've got the 3 files

`.xkb/types/mytypes`:

```
partial xkb_types "lock_level2" {
    Virtual_modifiers Lock;
    type "Lock_LEVEL2" {
        modifiers= Lock;
        map[Lock]= Level2;
        level_name[Level1]= "Base";
        level_name[Level2]= "Lock";
    };
};

partial xkb_types "alt_level2" {
    Virtual_modifiers Alt;
    type "ALT_LEVEL2" {
        modifiers= Alt;
        map[Alt]= Level2;
        level_name[Level1]= "Base";
        level_name[Level2]= "Alt";
    };
};
```

`.xkb/symbols/mysymbols`:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "Lock_brackets" {
    key <AC10>  {
        type[Group1] = "LOCK_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Odiaeresis,   bracketleft      ]
    };
    key <AC11>  {
        type[Group1] = "LOCK_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Adiaeresis,  bracketright       ]
    };
};

partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "alt_brackets" {
    key <AC10>  {
        type[Group1] = "ALT_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Odiaeresis,   braceleft      ]
    };
    key <AC11>  {
        type[Group1] = "ALT_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [    Adiaeresis,  braceright       ]
    };
};
```

`.xkb/keymap/mykdb`:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete+mytypes(lock_level2)+mytypes(alt_level2)" };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+de+inet(evdev)+mysymbols(lock_brackets)+mysymbols(alt_brackets)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

then running `xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY`.

But this doesn't seem to work for the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> modifiers, but does work
when I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> (instead of <kbd>Control</kbd>) and then it only works in Sublime and Firefox but not in Gnome and the Terminal.

So I'm wondering what's wrong with the current configuration and how I can set the mapping system-wide for all apps.